# ImportError: cannot import name overridden

Tags: python, nltk

So I am trying to work with `nltk` and have everything installed to the right environment. 
When I run the `import` commands individually everything works, however when I run all of my code in Python I get this error `ImportError`. 
Anyone know how I can fix this? Please help, thanks!

```
import nltk
import random
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
import pickle
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB, BernoulliNB
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, SGDClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC, NuSVC
from nltk.classify import ClassifierI
from statistics import mode
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
```

---

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code/pickle.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2./site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from nltk.internals import config_java
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 11, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 75, in <module>
    import pickle
  File "/Users/jpike/Desktop/Code/pickle.py", line 3, in <module>
    from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/classify/__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
    from nltk.classify.api import ClassifierI, MultiClassifierI
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/classify/api.py", line 21, in <module>
    from nltk.internals import overridden
ImportError: cannot import name overridden
```

Comment: Do you have _your own file_ `pickle.py`? If so, rename it.

Comment: Just renamed it -- I'm new to programming but I definitely see why I shouldn't name it that now

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was renamed the file /usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py to /usr/lib/python3.5/pickle2.py and the problem was solved. Not sure how this error related to import error. I just followed the instruction above given by DYZ

Comment: That sounds like you didn't follow DYZ instructions as this sounds like you renamed Python's pickly.py instead of **your own**.